# Using JavaScript to change a React Page Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swagger

So, I have an API that uses Swagger for it's documentation, swagger generates a ReactJs webpage to document and test the API endpoints. I know pretty much nothing about React architecture, So I don't exactly know what is causing this problem:

Before using any endpoint, you have to request a authentication Token, using another endpoint that performs a POST request to another API, that returns the Bearer Token.

Everytime I start the API for test purposes i have make the authorization request "manually" by putting the json in the textarea: [image]
Then I have to grab the token in the response, open the Authorization modal, and paste the token in the input:[image]

And I do that so many times. So i decided to create a little script in JS to make this process to me when i start the API Debugging. And that implies that the script changes the textarea/input values on the swagger page. When the value is changed, you can see it on the UI, but once the script simulates another action, like submitting the request, the changed value returns back to the old/default one.

Looks like it needs user interaction to update the page state?? i don't quite get it, i also tried after changing the values, trigger every change/update js event that i know, but didn't work either.

- What exactly React is doing here?
- is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT:** Example of what im doing:

I've installed [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools) as Ray Hatfield suggested, looks like the input is indeed a React Component

[image]

Im trying to update the state after I change the value:[image]

But still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally got it, to solve the React component not rerendering, i had to use Javascript's [PropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to get the native value setter of the input elements:

```
var ValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
    "value"
).set;
```

Then I called the ValueSetter Method passing the Node of the Input Element and it's new value:

```
ValueSetter.call(authInput, token);
```

And now just trigger the "Input" event, and for some reason I need to set the bubbling of the event to True, so the event get dispatched on the ancestrals elements (maybe react listen to some wrapper/main element triggers and it's children just bubble the event so it can get to it, idk...):

```
var inputEvent = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
authInput.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but…

Is your script changing the textarea value via direct DOM manipulation? e.g. `document.querySelector('textarea').value = json`? If so, it's likely that React doesn't see it because data/state generally flows downward into the DOM, not upward from the DOM.

My guess is that there's a React component that renders the textarea and registers a change listener on it. Change events from the textarea trigger a state update in the component, which rerenders the textarea to reflect the updated state.

You indicated that you've fired the change event, which seems like it should work given the scenario above. It's possible, though less likely, that the update is triggered via a keydown or keypress.

What I would suggest is that you install the [React devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) in your browser and use the "Components" view to inspect the textarea component. It might give you some insights into the state of the component, what events it's listening for, etc., and it would let you see what (if anything) changes when you run your script.

It also includes a button that will open the source code for the selected component. (In minimized apps without sourcemaps it might be impenetrable, but it's worth a look.)

[image: react devtool screenshot]